# What is a word or expression for a person who feels free?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

As in they feel unrestrained, like they could do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the term: *a free spirit*

> **free spirit**
>
> n. One who is not restrained, as by convention or obligation.

Reference: thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

'**Uninhibited**' would indicate being free of any limiting factors.

You say 'could do anything,' though, which implies much much more than mere lack of inhibition. The ability to do *anything* is what's known as '**omnipotence**.'

"I'm feeling omnipotent this morning!" is a strange, but humorous thing to say. If you would like to describe someone who takes unnecessary risks due to such a 'can do anything' attitude, a phrase commonly used to describe young men is '**10 feet tall and bulletproof**.'

It all depends on the nuance you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: **liberated**. A liberated person implies someone who is not chained nor imprisoned by social conventions. It is also associated with a sense of elation and general well-being.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "unbound"  "unshackled", "unfettered"  (as in unrestrained); or, with a more positive tilt, "liberated" as Mari-Lou pointed out.  Or you could use idiomatic phrasing, each with their nuances of connotation, such as "footloose and fancy free", "carefree", "free as a bird", or "on the loose" or "runnin' wild" (watch out world, here I come)